# How to use a dynamic button in another class

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic

I want to make a dynamic button and control it.

But I got an error in the line

```
MainMenuButton(true, Form);
```

How can I correct it?

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UI Teemp;

        ClientSize = new Size(Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height-35);
        Teemp.MainMenuButton(true, Form);
    }
}
```

and UI.cs

```
class UI
{
    public void MainMenuButton(Boolean Mode, Form Form1)
    {
        if (Mode == true) //Create
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Button StartB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            Form1.Controls.Add(StartB);
            StartB.Text = "Start";
            StartB.Top = 300;
            //StartB.Bottom = 100;
            StartB.Left = 400;
        }
        else
        {
            //  this.Controls.Remove(StartB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just use `static` keyword like `public static void MainMenuButton(Boolean Mode, Form Form1)` and instead of `Teemp.MainMenuButton(true, Form);` use `UI.MainMenuButton(true, Form);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the UI class first. `UI Teemp;` only declares a local variable of type **UI** but does not initializes it with an *UI* object instance. One cannot use uninitialized local variables.

When declaring the *Teemp* variable, you can at the same time initialize it with an *UI* object instance:

```
UI Teemp = new UI();
```

There is a second problem with your code. When invoking *MainMenuButton*, you will need to pass the Form object instance. In your code, `Form` is a type name and does not refer to an object instance. Use the *[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)* keyword:

```
Teemp.MainMenuButton(true, this);
```

The *[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)* keyword refers to the current instance of the class in which it is being used. With regard to your example, `this` would refer to the *Form1* object instance.

I also want to comment on another thing. Technically not being a problem, but naming your second argument of the *MainMenuButton* "Form1" can be confusing, since there is also a type named "Form1". With regard to C# it is generally recommended that the first letter in variable and argument names is lowercase, whereas the first letter in type names should be uppercase. Hence the source code for your *MainMenuButton* method could perhaps look similar like this:

```
public void MainMenuButton(bool createButton, Form form)
{
    if (createButton)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button startB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        form.Controls.Add(startB);
        startB.Text = "Start";
        startB.Top = 300;
        //startB.Bottom = 100;
        startB.Left = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        //  this.Controls.Remove(startB);
    }
}
```

Keeping variable and argument names different from type names avoids confusion when reading and writing code, thus lowering the risk of introducing bugs :)

Comment: Not completely correct. UI is not initialized at all and not with null.

Comment: @FlatEric, okay, then what is the value of the variable `Teemp` if you declare it like `UI Teemp;`?

Comment: You get a compile error when trying to access it. If you initialize it with null, you get a NullReferenceException at runtime

Comment: So, it is actually initialized with *null* (hence the NullReferenceException) and you contradict your first comment here. Read the first sentence in my answer :-)

Comment: Try to compile the original code from OP, it won't compile.

Comment: @FlatEric, you are right. I was confused and thinking about fields, but we obviously deal with local variables here doh...